# Logging the raw XML of a SOAP request/response using JAX-RPC

Tags: java, debugging, soap, jax-rpc

I'm using `JAX-RPC` and wanted to know if there is a way to make `JAX-RPC` print the raw SOAP Request/Response for debug purposes.

I saw that `JAX-RPC` uses `log4j` but did not see which logger I should turn on with `DEBUG` to view the message before it is sent.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you implement an `Handler` which will have an `handleRequest` and `handleResponse` method ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/rpc/handler/GenericHandler.html#handleResponse%28javax.xml.rpc.handler.MessageContext%29)) that you can override to manipulate your request/response ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28974/jaxrpchandlers.htm) on how to use handlers).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache Axis, here is the log4J configuration you can use:

```
<appender name="wsAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/MY_APP-ws.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="20MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %m%n" />
    </layout>
      <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter">
              <param name="StringToMatch" value="MY_SPECIFIC_WSProcessRequest" />
              <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
      </filter>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
</appender>

<logger name="org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="wsAppender"/>
</logger>
```

Change `MY_SPECIFIC_WSProcessRequest`for the specific value matching the XML request you want to log.